# Maximum update depth exceeded with this.props.history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to set up login-register routing for my web application.

The idea is:

- Login and Register
- If there is no authentication, it will direct to `/login` which will then render the `Login` component. If there is, I will direct to `/dashboard`
- In `Login`, if the user types correct username and password, it will redirect to `/dashboard`, else it doesn't do anything regarding routing.
- If the user visit `/` If there is any authentication, the user will redirect to `/dashboard` else to `/login`

I have tried to use `this.props.history.push` to redirect between the `Login`-`DashBoard` components.

Here are my routings so far, I don't know if this is best practice yet. If it is not, any bits of help would be appreciated.

Routing.js:

```js
...
   render() {
      return(
         <>
          <Route path="/login"><Login showAlert={this.showAlert}/></Route>
          <Route path="/register"><Register showAlert={this.showAlert}/></Route>

          <AuthRoute authed={AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()} path="/">
             <Dashboard/>
          </AuthRoute>

          <AuthRoute authed={AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()} path="/dashboard">
               <Dashboard/>
          </AuthRoute>
        </>
      )
...
```

Login.js:

```js
...
    componentDidMount() {
        if(AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
    }
...
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        AuthenticationService.authenticateAccount(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(() => {
                this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
            });
    }
...
export default withRouter(Login);
```

However, it has `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` although I use `componentDidMount()`

[image]

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
The problem only happens after clicking `login` from `/login`

Comment: You have an infinite loop when `AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()` is false. It just keeps pushing to go to login

Comment: @HMR I tried to put those code in the constructor but it has the same problem, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You can maybe use [match](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md) to check if current url is not already login:

Comment: @HMR I changed the code to         `if(AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn() && this.props.match !== '/dashboard') {` however the same error still happens. It only happens after click login.

Comment: Why would you go to login if you're not on dashboard? You should check that you are not already on login before going to logn

Comment: @HMR Thanks, I realize some logical error and decided to remove the middleware component (LoginRegister). In `Login.js` I guarded in `componentDidMount` to make sure that the user will be redirected to `/dashboard` if they are already logged in. However, the issue still exists.

Comment: What I meant is that you checked wrong, if not login and url is not login then push "/login", else do nothing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to escape this loop by comparing the router location to the push that I was trying to make, like so:

```
import { withRouter, useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

//...

const App = () =>  {

    //...

    const history = useHistory();

    const location = useLocation();

    const changePage = (change: { page: string, params: string, refresh: boolean}) => {

        if (location.pathname !== change.page || location.search !== change.param) {
     
            history.push({
                pathname: change.page,
                search: change.param
            });

        };

        if (change.refresh) {
            history.go(0);
        };

    };

    //...

};

export default withRouter(App);
```